# A case in which both test -n and test -z are true

Tags: linux, shell

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Please input 2 nums: "

read a b

if [ -z $b ]; then
        echo b is zero !
fi

if [ -n $b ]; then
        echo b is non-zero !
fi
```

when run the script, only input 1 number, and leave the other empty, then b is supposed to be null. but the result is both echo is printed.

```
-laptop:~$ ./test.sh 
Pleaes input 2 nums: 
5 
b is zero !
b is non-zero !
```

b is both null and non-null ?! Could anyone comment on this ? Thanks !

~

Comment: +1 for showing your code, and your actual output. Good luck!

Comment: If you're writing only for Bash, then you might want to replace the `[` conditionals with `[[`. Recommended reading here : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: You have a race condition here. The file size could change on disk between the two `if` tests. You should use `else` instead, if your code actually has this form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
if [ -z $b ]; then
```

with

```
if [ -z "$b" ]; then
```

And do the same in the other `if` condition as well.

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html for some interesting tests.

Comment: yes, it works ! thanks. but I wonder why "" makes so differences ?

Comment: Without the quotes, an uninitialized variable evaluates as _nothing_ so the shell evaluates `if [ -z ]`, which is true because the "-z" is parsed as a (non-empty) string, which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Bottom line: always quote your stuff where it does not interfere with other desired outcomes (e.g. expansion to multiple args).

Comment: @AdamLiss is right: the shell first counts the number of arguments inside `[ ... ]`. If it's just one argument, the result is true if the argument is not empty. As [the man page says](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test-122) "The `test` and `[` builtins evaluate conditional expressions using a set of rules based on the number of arguments."

Answer (score 3):

It's all in the quotes. I don't remember where, but someone explained this recently on SO or USE - Without the quotes it doesn't actually do an empty/non-empty string test, but just checks that `-n` or `-z` are *non-empty strings themselves*. It's the same test that makes this possible:

```
$ var=-n
$ if [ "$var" ]
then
    echo whut
fi
```

Returns `whut`.

This means you can also have a sort of functional programming:

```
$ custom_test() {
    if [ "$1" "$2" ]
    then
        echo true
    else
        echo false
    fi
}

$ custom_test -z "$USER"
false
$ custom_test -n "$USER"
true
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-n` test requires that the string be quoted within the test brackets. Using an unquoted string with `! -z`, or even just the unquoted string alone within test brackets normally works, however, this is an unsafe practice. Always quote a tested string.

```
$ b=''
$ [ -z $b ] && echo YES  # after expansion: `[ -z ] && echo YES` <==> `test -z && echo YES`
YES
$ [ -n $b ] && echo YES  # after expansion: `[ -n ] && echo YES` <==> `test -n && echo YES`
YES
```

`test` against nothing, yield `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as you mention, unquoted string in test normally work, but why this case fails ? Could you give some hints ?