# Why does the bash "test -n" command give the wrong result for the $@ (dollar at) positional parameter while "! test -z" works?

Tags: bash, shell

Using `$@` inside a bash `test` expression gives odd results.

Here's a minimal test script to reproduce the issue (among the alternative formulations for the same test which *do* pass without error):

```
#! /bin/bash
# file path: ./bash_weirdness.sh

echo "args: '$@'"

echo "--- empty ---"

if test "" ; then echo      "1.A1.TEST      - not empty?"; fi
if test -z "" ; then echo   "1.A2.EMPTY     - empty?"; fi
if test -n "" ; then echo   "1.A3.NE        - not empty?"; fi
if ! test "" ; then echo    "1.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?"; fi
if ! test -z "" ; then echo "1.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?"; fi
if ! test -n "" ; then echo "1.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?"; fi

echo "--- space ---"

if test " " ; then echo      "2.A1.TEST      - not empty?"; fi
if test -z " " ; then echo   "2.A2.EMPTY     - empty?"; fi
if test -n " " ; then echo   "2.A3.NE        - not empty?"; fi
if ! test " " ; then echo    "2.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?"; fi
if ! test -z " " ; then echo "2.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?"; fi
if ! test -n " " ; then echo "2.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?"; fi

echo "--- \$@ ---"

if test "$@" ; then echo      "3.A1.TEST      - not empty?"; fi
if test -z "$@" ; then echo   "3.A2.EMPTY     - empty?"; fi
if test -n "$@" ; then echo   "3.A3.NE        - not empty?"; fi
if ! test "$@" ; then echo    "3.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?"; fi
if ! test -z "$@" ; then echo "3.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?"; fi
if ! test -n "$@" ; then echo "3.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?"; fi

echo "--- \$* ---"

if test "$*" ; then echo      "4.A1.TEST      - not empty?"; fi
if test -z "$*" ; then echo   "4.A2.EMPTY     - empty?"; fi
if test -n "$*" ; then echo   "4.A3.NE        - not empty?"; fi
if ! test "$*" ; then echo    "4.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?"; fi
if ! test -z "$*" ; then echo "4.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?"; fi
if ! test -n "$*" ; then echo "4.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?"; fi
```

The first two sections ('empty' and 'space') are in there to verify that `test`, `test -n` and `test -z` work fine; that's how bad the confusion is.

The problem occurs when `$@` represents 'no arguments', i.e. when `$#` would be zero(0).

Three test runs show what's wrong: notice the '3.A3.NE - not empty?' report in the third run:

```
$ ./bash_weirdness.sh x
->
args: 'x'
--- empty ---
1.A2.EMPTY     - empty?
1.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?
1.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?
--- space ---
2.A1.TEST      - not empty?
2.A3.NE        - not empty?
2.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?
--- $@ ---
3.A1.TEST      - not empty?
3.A3.NE        - not empty?
3.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?
--- $* ---
4.A1.TEST      - not empty?
4.A3.NE        - not empty?
4.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?
```

Which is fine.

```
$ ./bash_weirdness.sh ""
->
args: ''
--- empty ---
1.A2.EMPTY     - empty?
1.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?
1.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?
--- space ---
2.A1.TEST      - not empty?
2.A3.NE        - not empty?
2.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?
--- $@ ---
3.A2.EMPTY     - empty?
3.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?
3.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?
--- $* ---
4.A2.EMPTY     - empty?
4.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?
4.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?
```

Which is fine too.

```
$ ./bash_weirdness.sh 
->
args: ''
--- empty ---
1.A2.EMPTY     - empty?
1.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?
1.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?
--- space ---
2.A1.TEST      - not empty?
2.A3.NE        - not empty?
2.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?
--- $@ ---
3.A2.EMPTY     - empty?
3.A3.NE        - not empty?
3.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?
--- $* ---
4.A2.EMPTY     - empty?
4.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?
4.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?
```

Which is ***not* fine at all**: notice the incorrect '3.A3.NE' result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While transforming this confusing observed behaviour into a test script and question that might be suitable for StackOVerflow, several things happened which led to the answer to this 'why' question.

> The TL;DR answer is in section 5 below; I describe the entire process of discovery because I (re)learned quite a few things along the way and I think others will follow the same, if not a very similar, path of discovery. Google is not *always* your friend!

### 1. total Google Fu fail

First, 'google' didn't deliver *anything* when you search for `bash test $@ odd result` or similar queries as it strips out the all-important `$@`. Rephrasing `$@` as `dollar at` didn't spit out anything useful either, which got me rather worried. I even started to suspect the bash I was running (mSysGit bash on Windows).

> Thanks to this debacle I went and looked up what the official name (jargon) for this `$@` might be (It's maybe 2 decades ago that I last read a bash manual; I've been *dabbling* in it ever since and this is the moment where I receive punishment for my laziness in not studying up on a language that I write (small bits of) code in.)

### 2. The name is: 'positional parameters'. `$@` (and `$*`)

Another round of searching led to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf which told me that `$@` (and `$*` - oh, right, had forgotten all about you!) are 'positional parameters'.

### 3. what *is* the *exact* behaviour of `test`?

During this search frenzy I also found http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#number_of_arguments_rules which explains how `test` behaves when the number of arguments is maybe not what you'ld expect.

But then I *did* have quotes around that `$@`, didn't I? 
So it *must* be a single argument for `test` then, even when the argument list is empty!? (`$# = 0`)

(Wrong! It isn't!)

#### The `test` expression evaluation rule set

Copying (with minimal edit to match it to this question) the very important section from the link above here -- this is what made my brain *click* a get a hunch, then a full understanding:

> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#number_of_arguments_rules:
>
> #### Number of Arguments Rules
>
> The `test` builtin, especially hidden under its `[` name, may seem simple but is in fact *causing a lot of trouble sometimes*. One of the difficulties is that the behaviour of `test` not only depends on its *arguments* but also on **the number of its arguments**.
>
> Here are the rules taken from the manual (Note: This is for the command `test`, for `[` the number of arguments is calculated without the final `]`, for example `[ ]` follows the "zero arguments" rule):
>
> - **0 arguments**
>
>   The expression is `false`.
> - **1 argument**
>
>   The expression is `true` if, and only if, the argument is *not null*.
> - **2 arguments**
>
>   If the first argument is `!` (exclamation mark), the expression is `true` if, and only if, the second argument is *null*.
>
>   If the first argument is one of the *unary conditional operators* listed above under the syntax rules (e.g. `-n` and `-z`), the expression is `true` if the unary test is `true`.
>
>   If the first argument is not a valid unary conditional operator, the expression is `false`.
> - **3 arguments**
>
>   If the second argument is one of the *binary conditional operators* listed above under the syntax rules, the result of the expression is the result of the binary test using the first and third arguments as operands.
>
>   If the first argument is `!`, the value is the negation of the *two-argument* test using the second and third arguments.
>
>   If the first argument is exactly `(` and the third argument is exactly `)`, the result is the *one-argument* test of the second argument. Otherwise, the expression is `false`. The `-a` and `-o` operators are considered *binary operators* in this case (**Attention**: This means the operator `-a` is *not* a *file operator* in this case!)
> - **4 arguments**
>
>   If the first argument is `!`, the result is the negation of the *three-argument expression* composed of the remaining arguments. Otherwise, the expression is parsed and evaluated according to precedence using the rules listed above.
> - **5 or more arguments**
>
>   The expression is parsed and evaluated according to precedence using the rules listed above.
>
> These rules may seem complex, but it's not so bad in practice. Knowing them might help you to explain some of the "unexplicable" behaviours you might encounter:

(note: the next section is **paraphrasing** the original to match this question!)

> ```
>  function test {
>    if [ -n "$@" ] ; then echo "argument list is not empty"; fi
>  }
>
>  test
> ```
>
> This code prints "argument list is not empty", even though `-n something` is supposed to be `false` if `something` is an empty string `""` - why?
>
> Here, `"$@"` expands to an **empty argument list**, i.e. `"$@"` results in actually **nothing** (Bash removes it from the command's argument list!). So the test is in fact `[ -n ]` and falls into the "*one argument*" rule, the only argument is "`-n`" which is *not null* and so the test returns `true`. Hence the usual solution, which is to quote the parameter expansion, e.g. `[ -n "$var" ]` so that the test has always 2 arguments, even if the second one is the null string, **does not work for `"$@"`**.
>
> These rules also explain why, for instance, `-a` and `-o` can have several meanings.

### 4. One more test run...

The description in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf and the non-obvious bits of behaviour of `test` as described in http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#number_of_arguments_rules drove me to run a fourth test with the test script specified in the question:

```
$ ./bash_weirdness.sh x y z
->
args: 'x y z'
--- empty ---
1.A2.EMPTY     - empty?
1.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?
1.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?
--- space ---
2.A1.TEST      - not empty?
2.A3.NE        - not empty?
2.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?
--- $@ ---
util/bash_weirdness.sh: line 25: test: y: binary operator expected
util/bash_weirdness.sh: line 26: test: too many arguments
util/bash_weirdness.sh: line 27: test: too many arguments
util/bash_weirdness.sh: line 28: test: y: binary operator expected
3.B1.NOT.TEST  - empty?
util/bash_weirdness.sh: line 29: test: too many arguments
3.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?
util/bash_weirdness.sh: line 30: test: too many arguments
3.B3.NOT.NE    - empty?
--- $* ---
4.A1.TEST      - not empty?
4.A3.NE        - not empty?
4.B2.NOT.EMPTY - not empty?
```

Now there's a hint!

### 5. Answering the 'why?' question

Now I know.

`$@`, even when quoted as `"$@"`, 'somehow' is transformed to the exact number of arguments available in `$@`, which for an empty argument list (`$# = 0`) means that `"$@"` represents exactly *nothing*: `test -n "$@"` therefor 'expands' to `test -n` which,
following the rules described in http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#number_of_arguments_rules, is almost identical to the example described there and follows the same '1 argument rule': the `-n` in `test -n` is therefor not the `test option: return true if string is non-empty` but rather that 'one argument', not null and consequently `test -n "$@" --> test -n --> test "-n" --> TRUE` which produces the unexpected erroneous test result shown in the third test run in the question.

The 'somehow' is due to what bash must do internally to guarantee that the number of parameters in `"$@"` *always* equals the number of rounds in loop statements such as `for f in "$@" ; do ... done` and *always* matches the number of parameters `$#`.

If the processing of `"$@"` for an *empty* parameter list would produce an empty string `""` rather than *nothing at all*, then such loop statements would execute *one(1)* round instead of the anticipated *zero(0)* rounds, which would be extremely counter-intuitive.

Once you've realized this, the description in  http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf for `$@` versus `$*` is obvious.

### 6. Deja Vu. Now that I know, SO suddenly delivers comparable questions (and answers)

This felt exactly like the old days when I was reading UNIX man pages after having worked with VMS: those 'man pages' were very concise and were more times than not only useful to me once I had already obtained the knowledge through other channels.

> #### [Edit] Retrospection Note:
>
> I say "wouldn't have helped me" for many SO questions listed below *only* because at the time when I was writing this answer I reflected and wondered if my question really was a *duplicate question* after all. These other questions, and the answers provided there, are all very valuable in their own right.
>
> The "wouldn't have helped me" phrase is there so you may understand that *my* brain needed something different to resolve my confusion and loss of trust in my machines. It is saying "I needed exactly this rather than one of those" and thus shows my internal argument whether this question of mine is a duplicate or not.
>
> My own conclusion now: one question *technically* is almost the same (apart from the `!` in `! test -z`), while its answers came very close to what I needed, but, to me at least, this isn't a duplicate *answer* as it pays much more attention to the depth of the details of the *why* of `test` and `$@` interaction. The precise question context required for this answer to be suitable makes this, at least to me, in retrospect, not a duplicate question. Though it comes close to being one.

Here they are:

- [A case in which both test -n and test -z are true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485729/a-case-in-which-both-test-n-and-test-z-are-true)

  my Google Fu failed me; this one would very probably have answered my question straight away.

  It lacks one important bit of detail which is the bit that made my brain fire up and initiate understanding: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#number_of_arguments_rules
- [Difference between $@ and $* in bash scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967074/difference-between-and-in-bash-scripting/17967121#17967121)

  Same subject; wouldn't have helped because it doesn't address the 'empty argument list' explicitly.

  The duplicate flag leads to:
- [Parsing/passing command line arguments to a bash script - what is the difference between "$@" and "$*"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649467/parsing-passing-command-line-arguments-to-a-bash-script-what-is-the-difference)

  Also wouldn't have worked for me. Unless perhaps if I'ld run the scripts listed in the answer there. The crux is that `"$@"` *eats* the quotes and produces exactly *nothing* when `$# = 0`. Which is not obvious from `"$1" ...`.
- [What is the difference between "$@" and "$*" in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)

  Wouldn't have helped me; the more elaborate description of `$@` given here doesn't mention the effect you get when you have *zero(0)* parameters (`$# = 0`); all consequences of the phase "starting with one" are clear only when you already know this peculiarity.
- [Idiomatic way to test if no positional params are given?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492338/idiomatic-way-to-test-if-no-positional-params-are-given)

  Which would have *circumvented* my problem due to too little active knowledge of the `bash` language: `$#` didn't belong to my 'active vocabulary` until about half an hour ago.

Comment: Some of the bash info at tldp is rather antiquated, with some questionable coding techniques, or just plain wrong. For a good up-to-date resource, check out the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and accompanying BashFAQ.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Thanks for the ref to the BashGuide! I checked their take on `$@` and they list github for edit submissions; I'll see if we can improve that documentation on the detail about `$@` where it expands to *nil* if the arglist is empty (`$# = 0`).

Answer (score 11):

### "$@" and `test` don't mix

```
test -n "$@"
```

This test isn't properly written. The `-n` test expects a single argument and tells you if that argument is an empty string or not. `"$@"` will expand into one word, multiple words, or even no words at all. It is therefore inappropriate to write `test -n "$@"`.

If you want to check that arguments were passed, use one of these:

```
test $# -gt 0
[[ $# -gt 0 ]]
(($# > 0))
(($#))
```

If you want to check that arguments were passed and also are non-empty, then use `"$*"` instead. `$*` always expands to a single string, so it's compatible with `test -n`.

```
test -n "$*"
[[ -n $* ]]
```

### The confusing case of `test -n`

```
$ test -n; echo $?
0
```

So why the heck does this test pass? Well, if you don't pass an argument to `-n` then bash doesn't see the `-n` as an operator. Instead, it understands the test as a form of

```
test STRING
```

If you write `test STRING` without an operator, it's implicitly equivalent to `test -n STRING`. `test STRING` is a shorthand way of testing if `STRING` is non-empty.

In other words, `test -n` is equivalent to

```
test -n '-n'
```

And this test passes since `'-n'` is a non-empty string.

### "$@" is awesome

By the way, the way `"$@"` behaves is in fact a great thing. `"$@"` is the best way to access the full argument list while handling whitespace correctly and avoiding issues with word splitting and globbing. When in doubt, use `"$@"`.

And if you want to store `"$@"` in a variable, use an array.

```
args=("$@")

for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

That will preserve the *multi-wordedness* of `"$@"`.

Comment: Re 'the confusing case of `test -n`': http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#number_of_arguments_rules helped me a lot to grok this: if you combine the ruleset described in that link with a notion of `"$@"` as 'expands to _**zero** or more_ quoted arguments'. The ruleset described in that link thus also helps to explain the errors shown in the fourth test run listed in the other answer, i.e. when `test -n "$@"` is fed *more than one* parameter (`$# > 1`).

Comment: Re 'confusing case of `test -n`': it's not just `test -n`; what got me stumped and started all this was `test -z` failing to meet my (uninformed) expectations.

Comment: I was about to say that `test -n` with no arguments should be a syntax error but it's needed for historical reasons. The alias for `test` is `[` and the usual syntax is `if [ $foo ]; then ...` which needs to evaluate to true if `$foo` contains `-n`. Note that such usage is very unsafe in any script with untrusted input.